# New API Key versus LoginKey for API V1.x

Tags: rally

In Rally's documentation for the new API Keys (https://help.rallydev.com/rally-application-manager) it says that while previously you needed to use a LoginKey for displaying information in external systems (such a sConfluence) that now you can generate an API key for each application. - However it does not indicate how you should replace the LoginKey for applications with a new API Key.

For external API V1 aps using the loginkey, do you just change out the LoginKey token in the query string (loginkey =) with the new API Key, or is there some other process for using the API Key (such as a different query string parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to replace LoginKey with API Key for API 1.x. The legacy apps written with AppSDK1 are expected to continue working with LoginKey for now.

API Key will be used to run new apps based on [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/) externally, without users being prompted to login, and support for this functionality is expected with the next release of AppSDK2.

Comment: Thanks nickm for the clarification - it is a bit confusing that there are release notes for functionality that is not yet useable (as it relates to a version of the APPSDK2 that is not yet released), and it then also mentions that it is a replacement for the LoginKey (which has only ever been available for V1), but in fact is not meant to work for V1. Maybe a cleanup of the release notes and the help page are in order?

Comment: I agree that release notes are not very clear, and the different rate of adaption of this new functionality by different toolkits adds to the confusion.
Unlike LoginKey, API Key is not exclusively intended for javascript apps running externally. Rally Ruby REST Toolkit has a built-in support for API Keys already:
https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForRuby .There are stories on the backlog to do the same for Java, .NET, rally-node toolkits, and of course AppSDK2, but there is no ETA yet.

Comment: rally-node was updated last week.  the java one is in progress currently.