# Rally loginkey alternatives to give visibility to Custom Reports and Dashboards without viewer providing authentication

Tags: rally

Is there a way to provide visibility to a custom dashboard or a Custom Report in Rally without the user having to supply login credentials.

The purpose is to be able to allow Executives or other such people who are not part of a Rally Project team, the ability to see dashboards and or reports, without them having to login to Rally.

I have tried the loginkey method but it is limited to the Standard Rally Reports.

```
https : //us1.rallydev.com/#/###########d/custom/#############?expandApp=##########
```

Looking at the following sites don’t help much in being able to figure out the exact means of accomplishing this.

[Github Login Component Example](https://github.com/RallyTools/Login-Component-Example)

[Help rallydev.com loginkey](https://help.rallydev.com/loginkey)

[Help rallydev.com multiple rally standard reports](https://help.rallydev.com/multiple-rally-standard-reports-one-sharepoint-webpart)

Answer (score 0):

LoginKey is not limited to standard reports. Custom apps can also be displayed outside of Rally without having to login as long as valid LoginKey is supplied with read-only user's encoded credentials.

LoginKey is legacy technology that works with legacy AppSDK1.
AppSDK2 does not support LoginKey. What SDK your custom apps are based on: [AppSDK1](https://help.rallydev.com/app-sdk) or [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/) ? See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23393949/new-api-key-versus-loginkey-for-api-v1-x).

There are no plans to update LoginKey to work with AppSDK2, but a new technology that is currently being worked on is expected to allow displaying Rally custom apps outside of Rally without having to login.

A LoginKey documentation is available in [this github repo](https://github.com/RallyTools/Login-Component-Example).

You explicitly asked about visibility to a custom dashboard. It is tricky.
The documentation in github includes an iframe example that is **not supported**, but allows display of an entire dashboard. There are security considerations.

There is another significant drawback to  this method: it exposes the entire Rally navigation. However if a user creates a custom page with a custom app or a catalog app in it, that page can be accessed via iframe src in a custom app in a *full screen mode*. This does not apply to Dashboard or reports on Report tab, but a custom page that can be displayed in a full screen mode inside Rally can also be referenced with `?expandApp` option, to display in a full screen mode outside of Rally as well, e.g.

```
iframe.src = "https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/#/3333d/custom/12345?expandApp=67890";
```

Here are the details:

Add a custom app to a custom page in Rally.

View this app in a full screen mode. Note the URL changes from

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/3333d/custom/12345
```

to

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/3333d/custom/12345?expandApp=67890
```

Here is the code fragment where this URL is used, with "loginapi" added in front of "rally1":

```
 var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
                iframe.src = "https://loginapirally1.rallydev.com/#/3333d/custom/12345?expandApp=67890"; //USE YOUR PROJECT AND CUSTOM PAGE OIDs
                iframe.width = 1000;
                iframe.height = 800;
                document.getElementById("grid").appendChild(iframe);
```

Your URL will be different. Make sure your read-only user has permissions to access a project where your app is installed.

Once again, using iframe has drawbacks, and one of them, the exposure of the entire navigation can only be overcome in full screen mode. But this mode will work with individual apps and will not work with entire dashboard.